# Screen glitches / artifacts / flickering on all modern distros and kernels. I haven't been able to find solution for over half a year

Tags: linux, kernel, intel-graphics, visual-artifacts, intel

Horizontal lines, glitches, black or white horizontal bars appear randomly on the screen. It's very, very random. Sometimes it's barely noticeable, sometimes it's like on two videos below.
The issue has been there for almost a year. I think it started appearing arount 5.15-5.19 kernel.

Glitches don't appear in BIOS, refind menu, Grub or Windows. Everything is perfect there.

There also seems to be no problems with Nvidia graphics on Linux and external displays.

Videos:

- Pop OS on generic kernel:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0SSLWwTSKk
- Pop OS on Xanmod Edge:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BD8Uz7lmtaY
- Fedora 39 KDE live:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyZj4bB6mq8

I've also tested on Kubuntu, Mint and MX (don't have videos but I haven't been able to find any distro that doesn't have this glitch).

Laptop specs:

- i7 8750h
- 16GB 2666MHz
- GTX 1050ti mobile (usually disabled in linux, internal display is connected to intel graphics)
- 144Hz 1080p internal display
- TongFang GK5CN5Z (sold by XMG, OverPowered, Mechrevo, PCSpecialist, Illegear, BTO, HyperBook, Eluktronics, CyberPowerPC under various names)

What I've tried so far:

- Multiple distros, live and local, reinstalling them.
- Setting various kernel parameters related to intel graphics. max cstate seems to mitigate the problem a bit, just a little while other parameters don't do anything noticeable.
- Installing different kernels and versions, generic, lowlatency, xanmod, liquorix from 6.0 to 6.7.2 (tested about 40 kernels).
- Checking for hardware damage, replugging internal display cable, it all seems perfect and works on Windows.
- Changing refresh rate.
- Tweaking many parameters in Linux, I don't remember most of them, I've made at least 100-200 various changes.